# change font size after using google translate

Tags: css, wordpress, translation

I am using a `WordPress` theme and i have installed the `Google` translate plugin.

I'm having an issue after I translate the language. The font size is entirely to large after the change from English to any language. I have researched and found that I could use `:lang pseudo` tag, however when i inspect with firebug the `html` class of my page is still "en-US" so would the `:lang pseudo` tag work?

If so how do i know what to call when i switch it to french? I have been researching this for hours and have yet to find a solution. Here is a link to the website, any help would be greatly appreciated

http://rightbrainmediaanddesign.com/wordpress_jinja/

///update 1:09am ET///
I found that after translation it was wrapping my text in `<font>` tags so if i call that in the css it allows me to change it universally for any translation, however I still cannot target a specific language. Here is what i did. `#primary-menu font {
   font-size: 11px !important;
}` Now that did the trick, but as i said it is universal for any translation i.e. from english to any language. Now the challange is to be able to change just french or just spanish.

Comment: your drop down has no language option but if you have css rules for your body's font it shouldn't be changing the font size no matter what language you change to

Comment: The language selector does work, make sure your flash plugin is enabled. And your right it doesnt make it larger after the change. However when you change from english to lets say french each word holds more characters, so I want to change the font size and make it smaller for each different language.

Comment: as far as i can see the translation of english word is bigger in french and maybe smaller in some other language. so what you should do is create a css that holds perfectly for any language.

Comment: Yea, thats gonna be what I do if i cant find a solution to control the specific language.

Comment: Thers no other way lets say later on sometime u want to add serbian or russian language do you want to change the structure again

Comment: yes, I would want exactly that, I know it seems like extra steps, but it would allow me full control as far as the design goes. I wouldnt mind having to go back and do it for each language, I feel like it would bother me more that the design doesnt look or fit into place the way i want it to. Its my OCD haha.

Comment: i came across a temporary solution, I updated what i found in my question.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Okay, ISSUE SOLVED!! I downloaded a different wordpress plugin here it is.
>
> http://transposh.org/
>
> Now this plugin ties into the Google Translate API, however unlike the google plugin this one actually changes the `lang=""` in the `<html>` section above the header. So, in your css, to reference a specific language in the css it would look like this(for those that dont know) `html:lang(es)` That would be for spanish, to reference a specific div it would look like `html:lang(es) #primary-menu {}`. To locate your language abbreviation, just inspect your document and you will see it located at the very top of the html in this case it says `lang="es"`. I sure hope this helps someone out there, because it just did wonders for me.